# How do SQL EXISTS statements work?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL and am having a hard time understanding EXISTS statements. I came across this quote about "exists" and don't understand something:

> **Using the exists operator, your subquery can return zero, one, or many rows, and the condition simply checks whether the subquery returned any rows. If you look at the select clause of the subquery, you will see that it consists of a single literal (1); since the condition in the containing query only needs to know how many rows have been returned, the actual data the subquery returned is irrelevant.**

What I don't understand is how does the outer query know which row the subquery is checking? For example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM suppliers
 WHERE EXISTS (select *
                 from orders
                where suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id);
```

I understand that if the id from the supplier and orders table match, the subquery will return true and all the columns from the matching row in the suppliers' table will be outputted. What I don't get is how the subquery communicates which specific row (lets say the row with supplier id 25) should be printed if only a true or false is being returned.

It appears to me that there is no relationship between the outer query and the subquery.

Answer (score 118):

Think of it this way:

For 'each' row from `Suppliers`, check if there 'exists' a row in the `Order` table that meets the condition `Suppliers.supplier_id` (this comes from Outer query current 'row') `= Orders.supplier_id`.  When you find the first matching row, stop right there - the `WHERE EXISTS` has been satisfied.

The magic link between the outer query and the subquery lies in the fact that `Supplier_id` gets passed from the outer query to the subquery for each row evaluated.

Or, to put it another way, the subquery is executed for each table row of the outer query.

It is NOT like the subquery is executed on the whole and gets the 'true/false' and then tries to match this 'true/false' condition with outer query.

Comment: Thanks! "It is NOT like subquery executed on the whole and gets the 'true/false', and then tries to match this 'true/false' condition with outerquery." is what really cleared it up for me, I keep thinking that's how subqueries work (and many times they do), but what you said makes sense because the subquery relies on the outer query and therefore must be executed once per row

Comment: Thank you @sojin, your explanation is very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 32):

> It appears to me that there is no relationship between the outer query and the subquery.

What do you think the WHERE clause inside the EXISTS example is doing?   How do you come to that conclusion when the SUPPLIERS reference isn't in the FROM or JOIN clauses within the EXISTS clause?

EXISTS valuates for TRUE/FALSE, and exits as TRUE on the first match of the criteria -- this is why it can be faster than `IN`.  Also be aware that the SELECT clause in an EXISTS is ignored - IE:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM SUPPLIERS s
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1/0
                 FROM ORDERS o
                WHERE o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id)
```

...should hit a division by zero error, but it won't.  The WHERE clause is the most important piece of an EXISTS clause.

Also be aware that a JOIN is not a direct replacement for EXISTS, because there will be duplicate parent records if there's more than one child record associated to the parent.

Comment: I'm still missing something. If it exits at the first match, how does the output end up being all results where o.supplierid = s.supplierid? Wouldn't it just output the first result instead?

Comment: @Dan: The `EXISTS` exits, returning TRUE on the first match - because the supplier exists at least once in the ORDERS table.  If you wanted to see the duplication of the SUPPLIER data because of having more than one child relationship in ORDERS, you'd have to use a JOIN.  But most don't want that duplication, and running GROUP BY/DISTINCT is liable to add overhead to the query.  `EXISTS` is more efficient than `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM SUPPLIERS JOIN ORDERS ...` on SQL Server, haven't tested on Oracle or MySQL lately.

Comment: I had a question, is the matching done for every record that is SELECTED in the outer query. As in do we fetch from Orders 5 times if there are 5 rows selected from Suppliers.

Answer (score 30):

You can produce identical results using either `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, `IN`, or `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT o.supplier_id FROM orders o) o
    ON o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id

SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders o WHERE o.supplier_id = s.supplier_id)

SELECT s.supplier_id 
FROM suppliers s 
WHERE s.supplier_id IN (SELECT o.supplier_id FROM orders o)

SELECT s.supplier_id
FROM suppliers s
INTERSECT
SELECT o.supplier_id
FROM orders o
```

Comment: great answer, but also mind that it is better not to use exists to avoid correlation

Comment: Which query do you think will run faster if suppliers has 10M rows and orders has 100M rows and why?

Comment: I just ran these (or equivalent from my sample database) through SSMS. The first one the `INNER JOIN`) was slightly longer. The other three actually had the same execution plan, so it’s really a matter of what you prefer.

Answer (score 8):

### Database table model

Let’s assume we have the following two tables in our database, that form a one-to-many table relationship.

[image: SQL EXISTS tables]

The `student` table is the parent, and the `student_grade` is the child table since it has a student_id Foreign Key column referencing the id Primary Key column in the student table.

The `student table` contains the following two records:

```
| id | first_name | last_name | admission_score |
|----|------------|-----------|-----------------|
| 1  | Alice      | Smith     | 8.95            |
| 2  | Bob        | Johnson   | 8.75            |
```

And, the `student_grade` table stores the grades the students received:

```
| id | class_name | grade | student_id |
|----|------------|-------|------------|
| 1  | Math       | 10    | 1          |
| 2  | Math       | 9.5   | 1          |
| 3  | Math       | 9.75  | 1          |
| 4  | Science    | 9.5   | 1          |
| 5  | Science    | 9     | 1          |
| 6  | Science    | 9.25  | 1          |
| 7  | Math       | 8.5   | 2          |
| 8  | Math       | 9.5   | 2          |
| 9  | Math       | 9     | 2          |
| 10 | Science    | 10    | 2          |
| 11 | Science    | 9.4   | 2          |
```

### SQL EXISTS

Let’s say we want to get all students that have received a 10 grade in Math class.

If we are only interested in the student identifier, then we can run a query like this one:

```
SELECT
    student_grade.student_id
FROM
    student_grade
WHERE
    student_grade.grade = 10 AND
    student_grade.class_name = 'Math'
ORDER BY
    student_grade.student_id
```

But, the application is interested in displaying the full name of a `student`, not just the identifier, so we need info from the `student` table as well.

In order to filter the `student` records that have a 10 grade in Math, we can use the EXISTS SQL operator, like this:

```
SELECT
    id, first_name, last_name
FROM
    student
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM
        student_grade
    WHERE
        student_grade.student_id = student.id AND
        student_grade.grade = 10 AND
        student_grade.class_name = 'Math'
)
ORDER BY id
```

When running the query above, we can see that only the Alice row is selected:

```
| id | first_name | last_name |
|----|------------|-----------|
| 1  | Alice      | Smith     |
```

The outer query selects the `student` row columns we are interested in returning to the client. However, the WHERE clause is using the EXISTS operator with an associated inner subquery.

The EXISTS operator returns true if the subquery returns at least one record and false if no row is selected. The database engine does not have to run the subquery entirely. If a single record is matched, the EXISTS operator returns true, and the associated other query row is selected.

The inner subquery is correlated because the student_id column of the `student_grade` table is matched against the id column of the outer student table.

Comment: What a great answer. I think I didn't get the concept because I was using a wrong example. Does `EXIST` only work with correlated subquery? I was playing around with query containing only 1 table, like `SELECT id FROM student WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student WHERE student.id > 1)`. I know what I wrote could be achieved by one simple WHERE query but I was just using it to understand EXISTS. I got all the rows. Is it indeed due to the fact that I didn't use correlated subquery? Thanks.

Comment: It makes sense only for correlated subqueries as you want to filter the records of the outer query. In your case  the inner query can be replaced with WHERE TRUE

Comment: Thanks Vlad. That's what I thought. It's just a weird idea that occurred when I was messing around with it. I honestly didn't know the concept of correlated subquery. And now it makes a lot more sense to filter out rows of the outer query with the inner query.

Answer (score 7):

If you had a where clause that looked like this:

```
WHERE id in (25,26,27) -- and so on
```

you can easily understand why some rows are returned and some are not.

When the where clause is like this:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select * from orders where suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id);
```

it just means : return rows that have an existing record in the orders table with te same id.

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS means that the subquery returns at least one row, that's really it. In that case, it's a correlated subquery because it checks the supplier_id of the outer table to the supplier_id of the inner table. This query says, in effect:

SELECT all suppliers
For each supplier ID, see if an order exists for this supplier
If the supplier is not present in the orders table, remove the supplier from the results
RETURN all suppliers who have corresponding rows in the orders table

You could do the same thing in this case with an INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT suppliers.* 
  FROM suppliers 
 INNER 
  JOIN orders 
    ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

Ponies comment is correct. You'd need to do grouping with that join, or select distinct depending on the data you need.

Comment: The inner join will produce different results than EXISTS if more than one child record is associated with a parent -- they are not identical.

Comment: I think my confusion might be that I've read that the subquery with an EXISTS returns true or false; but this can't be the only thing that it returns, right? Is the subquery also returning all "suppliers who have corresponding rows in the orders table"? But if it is, how is the EXISTS statement returning a boolean result? Everything I'm reading in text books is saying that it only returns a boolean result, so I'm having a hard time reconciling the result of the code with what I'm being told it returns.

Comment: Read EXISTS like a function... EXISTS(resultset). The EXISTS function would then return true if the resultset has rows, false if it's empty. That's basically it.

Comment: @Dan, consider that EXISTS() is logically evaluated for *every* source row independently - it is not single value for entire query.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that `EXISTS` is `SEMI JOIN` in disguise. Most SQL dialects do not have `SEMI JOIN` in their syntax but provide `EXISTS` instead which amounts to the same thing. It's just like `INNER JOIN` except that

- the right table is suppressed in the output
- the rows in the left table are never duplicated

By the same token, `NOT EXISTS` corresponds to `ANTI JOIN`.

Answer (score -1):

What you describe is a so called query with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

(In general) it's something that you should try to avoid by writing the query by using a join instead:

```
SELECT suppliers.* 
FROM suppliers 
JOIN orders USING supplier_id
GROUP BY suppliers.supplier_id
```

Because otherwise, the subquery will be executed for each row in the outer query.

Comment: Those two solutions are not equivalent. The JOIN gives a different result than the EXISTS subquery if there is more than one row in `orders` that is matching the join condition.

Comment: thanks for the alternate solution. but do you suggest that if given a option between correlated subquery and join, i should go with join because it is more efficient?