# Exist error in subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

I am trying to do some counts. The first sub query is the total scanned count. The second sub query is scanned count within 60 minutes. Sorry in advance for this being compressed. Both run correctly when separate.

I am getting a "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub query is not introduced with EXISTS" error at lines 12 and 22 I am not familiar with Exists.

```
SELECT
MONTH(F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.SCHEDULED_DATETIME) AS MONTH
,V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS UNIT
,(SELECT DISTINCT 
MONTH(F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.SCHEDULED_DATETIME) AS MONTH
,V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS UNIT
,count(med_scanned_bool)
FROM F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN
INNER JOIN V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE ON F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.ORDER_MED_ID=V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.ORDER_MED_ID AND LINE=MAR_LINE
WHERE MED_SCANNED_BOOL=1
GROUP BY MONTH(SCHEDULED_DATETIME), V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME
) AS SCANNED_D
,(SELECT DISTINCT
MONTH(F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.SCHEDULED_DATETIME) AS MONTH
,V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS UNIT
,count(med_scanned_bool) AS SCANNED_N
FROM F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN
INNER JOIN V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE ON F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.ORDER_MED_ID=V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.ORDER_MED_ID AND LINE=MAR_LINE
WHERE MED_SCANNED_BOOL=1
AND SECONDS_AFTER_SCHEDULED<'3600' --Within 60 Minute Window
GROUP BY MONTH(SCHEDULED_DATETIME), V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME
)AS SCANNED_N

FROM F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN
INNER JOIN V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE ON F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.ORDER_MED_ID=V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.ORDER_MED_ID AND LINE=MAR_LINE
```

Comment: you need to format that code and learn how to turn OFF the capslock key while writing sql...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do SQL EXISTS statements work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work)

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT DISTINCT 
   MONTH(F_IP_HSP_SUM_MED_ADMIN.SCHEDULED_DATETIME) AS MONTH,
   V_MAR_BARCODE_COMPLIANCE.DEPARTMENT_NAME AS UNIT,
   count(med_scanned_bool)
...) AS SCANNED_D
```

In the column selection part of the query, you can only have subselects that return *one* column, not 3.

If you're using a database with common table expression support, you may be able to replace the multi column subselect with joining with a CTE.

Comment: Ok thanks for that info....I kinda knew that but wasn't sure. took your advice Joachim. now I get this error. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @user2414620 It would seem your subselect returns more than one row, which is not allowed, once again since it's in the column selection part of the query. Since the column selection only tells what the values to return are for one row, you can't have one value be multiple rows. It sounds like your subselect maybe should be joined in in the `FROM` part of the query instead, that will allow both multiple columns and rows.

Comment: you can do subselects in from statement? can you give example of what your saying?