# I dont understand the error with the syntax in SQL

Tags: sql, ingres

```
Insert into tbproppayh (id_payment)
SELECT s.id_payment FROM session.set_values s
WHERE EXISTS id_payment;
```

Thu Jul 18 10:21:42 2013
Executing . . .

```
    E_US09C5 line 1, Syntax error on 'id_payment'.  The correct syntax is:
        SELECT [ALL|DISTINCT] target_list
          FROM table(s)
          [WHERE search_cond]
          [GROUP BY col(s)]
          [HAVING search_cond]
     [UNION subselect]
     [ORDER BY col(s)]
        (Thu Jul 18 10:21:42 2013)
```

continue

Comment: i'd say that your error is in your `WHERE EXISTS ...` part.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(attribute) VALUES(STATEMENT OBTAINING VALUE)

Comment: Your subquery may have to be inside where exits, like, Insert into table (field) where exists(select field from table2). Can you check this. BTW, which server you are using?

Comment: To add to @STTLCU's comment, `WHERE EXISTS` expects a subquery to follow, and `id_payment` is a column instead of a subquery.

Comment: im using ingres in a shell script for testing

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tbproppayh (id_payment)
SELECT s.id_payment
FROM   session.set_values s
WHERE  id_payment IS NOT NULL;
```

`WHERE EXISTS` needs a subquery:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... FROM ...)
```

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work).

After your comment, just use `DISTINCT` to avoid inserting duplicate values:

```
INSERT INTO tbproppayh (id_payment)
SELECT DISTINCT s.id_payment
FROM   session.set_values s
WHERE  id_payment IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: ok thats seems to be better but now i have a duplicate key on insert  error

Comment: That's independant. That means you have duplicates id_payment values in your set_values table, and that id-payment is tbproppayh's primary key.

Comment: i think i understand now, there are duplicate in my set values table ok , so how can a stop it pulling duplicates

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. This way you won't insert any dupes.

Comment: Thanks a million, life saver