# Insert then delete rows out of an oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to see if there is a better way to do this.  The statement takes all rows that happened further out than 6 months and puts them into an archive table.  Then it takes all the ids present in both tables and removes them from the main table.  Any Ideas?

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveTable
    SELECT *
    FROM MainTable
    WHERE DateItHappened < (SYSDATE - 180);

DELETE FROM MainTable a
   WHERE a.ID IN (
   SELECT b.ID 
   FROM ArchiveTable b 
   JOIN MainTable a
     ON b.ID = 
        a.ID);
```

Update:

I went ahead and implemented Joe's suggestion below to make this the final code.  If anyone has any changes that should be made please let me know.

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveTable
    SELECT *
    FROM MainTable
    WHERE DateItHappened < (SYSDATE - 180);

DELETE FROM maintable a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1         
     FROM archivetable b
    WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: I think your approach is good. Doesn't work? And the answer below... better leave it there.

Comment: @ThrashBean are you referring to my answer?  Please provide details if so.

Comment: No @Joe, sorry, the first one, about sql server. I wrote my comment before your answer. And your answer is good.

Comment: @ThrashBean Ok - just making sure!

Comment: The code works, but I'm not a seasoned Oracle developer so I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything since this will be used in a nightly process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DELETE can be simplified:

```
DELETE FROM maintable a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM archivetable b
                WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: This works.  Would you mind explaining what that select statement does?

Comment: Sure. The SELECT just checks for the existence of the specified value in the other table. If the condition is satisfied (that is, the SELECT produces a row), then the EXISTS is considered TRUE. Note that the "1" in the SELECT is only a placeholder -- it's only there to make it a valid SQL statement.  See more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work

Comment: I think what I didn't understand previously is that it is calling that select statement once per row in 'a'. I'm working with test data so far, but does anyone have performance related data to which method is more efficient? I've read IN is slightly slower than EXISTS, but what about when we're deleting 40 to 50 thousand rows?

Comment: A correlated EXISTS is generally rewritten to a semi-join, as is an IN clause. EXISTS is not so tricky with NULLS, and is my usual choice.

Answer (score 1):

My usual approach is to use a global temporary table to store the rowid's of the rows that I'm moving from the source table to the target table, then using that set to perform the deletes. It makes it 100% safe for such issues as an unstable initial data set.

```
insert all
  into archivetable (col1, col2 ...)
  values (col1, col2 ...)
  into maintable_deletes (delete_rowid)
  values (rowid)
select rowid, *
from   maintable;

delete from maintable
where  rowid in (select delete_rowid from maintable_deletes);

commit;
```

The GTT is useful because it can delete its own rows on commit.

Comment: I wish I had that kind of permission on the table because this is definitely safer.  Security checks have me limited to the basics only unfortunately.

Comment: It will range from 40 to 50 thousand a day most likely. First day will be gigantic.

Comment: No partitioning option, I suppose?

Comment: I looked into it briefly, but without being able to create and alter tables, coercing our database security team to setup a repartition before every archive seemed unlikely.  Another requirement I have is that existing code work unaltered, i.e. MainTable must reference the table that contains the last 6 months of data. With a partition I believe the reference changes leaving my hands tied.

Comment: Difficult to see what security problem could be involved in creating a new partition for a table, especially as you don't need ALTER TABLE privileges -- you can encapsulate the logic in a procedure and call that instead. It sounds like the organisational problems are greater than the technical ones in your organisation.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server it would be like, but oracle does not have a built in method to do this:

```
delete m
output deleted.ColumnA, deleted.ColumnB
into ArchiveTable
from 
MainTable m
where DateItHappened < (SYSDATE - 180);
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on an oracle version of that, and I can't get it to execute, so I'm guessing no. Thanks for the input!

Comment: To bad, its a nice feature!