# How does the EXISTS Clause work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried with below queries and bit confused about working of `EXISTS` clause, although I know it evaluates for `TRUE/FALSE`.

Below #1 SQL sub-query anyhow returns 0, but still the result of the combined query is 1.

```
1. SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 1 )

2. SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 0 )
```

Also, if `EXISTS` clause evaluates for `TRUE/FALSE`, then why does the below one not work?

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( 1 )
```

Please help me understand this situation.

**EDIT:** `EXISTS` clause evaluates for `TRUE/FALSE`.
 The condition is `TRUE` if a sub-query returns any result. Then why `EXISTS ( 1 )` does not work ? It is a `TRUE` condition.

Comment: If the `EXISTS`' sub-select returns any row at all, the `EXISTS` is `TRUE`. (The value(s) returned doesn't matter, only if any rows are returned or not.)

Comment: another solution can be using `@@rowcount` system variable `IF @@rowcount > 1` which contains last count of rows affected or read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do SQL EXISTS statements work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work)

Comment: @PathumAnjana, please review EDIT.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. Now I understand.

Comment: You could say: `SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 )`. The argument of EXISTS is always a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

> Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 1 )
-- there is row

SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 0 )
-- no row returned by subquery

SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS ( 1 )
-- not even valid query `1` is not subquery
```

Keep in mind that it checks rows not values so:

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL WHERE 1 = 1 )
-- will return 1
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/429367?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

> This seems contradictory with the sentence " EXISTS clause evaluates for TRUE/FALSE" ?

`EXISTS` operator tests for the existence of rows and it returns `TRUE/FALSE`.

So if subquery returns:

```
╔══════════╗     ╔══════════╗     ╔══════════╗     ╔══════════╗
║ subquery ║     ║ subquery ║     ║ subquery ║     ║ subquery ║
╠══════════╣     ╠══════════╣     ╠══════════╣     ╠══════════╣
║ NULL     ║     ║ 1        ║     ║ 0        ║     ║anything  ║
╚══════════╝     ╚══════════╝     ╚══════════╝     ╚══════════╝
```

Then `EXISTS (subquery)` -> `TRUE`.

If subquery returns (no rows):

```
╔══════════╗
║ subquery ║
╚══════════╝
```

Then `EXISTS (subquery)` -> `FALSE`.

Comment: Now I understand, it checks for rows & not the values. This seems contradictory with the sentence " EXISTS clause evaluates for TRUE/FALSE" ?

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS returns true when the subquery within it has any rows.  A logically equivalent (but not recommended) way of rewriting an EXISTS expression is:

```sql
SELECT 1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT 0 WHERE 1 = 1)) > 0
```

In this rewriting, your last query looks like:

```sql
SELECT 1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 1) > 0
```

which you should see doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior:

```
Condition          Is true if ...
----------         ------------------
EXISTS             the subquery returns at least one row
NOT EXISTS         the subquery returns no data
```

Usage:

```
WHERE EXISTS ( subquery );
WHERE NOT EXISTS  ( subquery );
```