# How does NOT EXISTS work in this question

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, exists

## Question

- Finish the SQL query to select the ID and the data of the root:

  > SELECT ➀
  >   FROM Node
  >   WHERE ➁
- A ➀ id, data ➁ parent id IS NULL
- B None of the other answers
- C ➀ id, data ➁ parent id = NULL
- D ➀ id, data ➁ NOT EXISTS parent id
- E ➀ parent id, data ➁ id != NULL

Right answer is A, which I understand, but why can't it be D? I don't fully understand NOT EXISTS I suppose..

Comment: Check out the following for details on the `EXISTS` keyword: [Stack Overflow Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work)
and
[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I suppose you have a syntax error; [`EXISTS` is a predicate that takes a subquery](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php), not a binary operation like your example suggests.

Comment: No I'm sorry had wrong structure but I've edited now

Comment: @MrKnudz 9000 is suggesting that option D is a syntax error because the `EXISTS` keyword expects a subquery: `EXISTS ( subquery )`. So, something like `NOT EXISTS (select [parent id] from [table])` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: @gbeaven Aha misunderstood, okay thanks I understand now!

Comment: It would have to be something like `SELECT id FROM NODE as somealias WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Node WHERE somealias.parent_id = Node.id)` (or similar) which is a silly query when `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` is essentially doing the same thing without the extra lookup.

Comment: Yes did not understand that EXISTS needed subquery statements for SYNTAX to work so thanks a lot for your input!