# Why Are table rows passed from main query to subquery, rather the whole table, in sql EXIST operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, exists

I've been learning sql from w3school and got to the [`EXIST` operator chapter](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp). I am also studying this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work).

The main example being used is this:

```
SELECT SupplierName
FROM Suppliers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID AND Price < 20);
```

I know that `WHERE` clause checks the condition for each row. Now if I run the subquery on it's own I'd get an error:

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.supplierID AND Price < 20)
```

Error: `Suppliers` is undefined.

What I don't understand is why does the subquery use only one row from the `Suppliers` table from the main query? I know this must be true, because if the subquery uses the whole `Suppliers` table then it would return true always and we would display all suppliers, even the ones with `Price > 20`.

The linked [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379739/3429430) also mentions this:

> The magic link between the outer query and the subquery lies in the fact that Supplier_id gets passed from the outer query to the subquery for each row evaluated.

So, can someone direct me to an official reference for any sql language which mentions/explains that the subquery doesn't use the whole `Suppliers` table, but one particular row(the one being selected in the main query).

Comment: WHERE condition is tested for each separate row. In this moment the expression `Suppliers.supplierID` have one definite value taken from the row which is tested. When you try to execute the correlated subquery itself this value don't exist which produces an error. You may insert some definite value taken from some `Suppliers` table's row instead of this column name (some `123` value), and the query will be executed like it is executed during WHERE testing for this row. Study "correlated subquery".

Comment: The key point (that @Akina also mentions) is that the subquery is a **correlated** subquery. Correlated subqueries have references to the immediately superior queries (in this case the main query), and access data based on conditions related to it.

Comment: Thanks guys, it would be great if someone could also put this info as an answer with a(some) reference(s) to back that up. I am not seeking for a resource recommendation, but an answer backed up with an authoritative reference. Cheers.