# Why SQL sort function can increase table matching speed?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, azure-sql-database, left-join

This is a SQL interview question:

There are two tables, table_A (customer_id, name) (assuming n rows), table_B (customer_id, order_id) (assuming k rows)

Goal:  Find customers that did not make any order

My solution is:

```
select customer_id from table_A 

left join table_B using (customer_id)

where order_id is null
```

Clearly, this is not the most efficient way. since it needs to go through n*k times iterations

The interviewer suggest a better way that I should sort the table_B first  since it could reduce the iteration time to n*log(k) (not very sure If I got/understand his suggestion )

Could anyone better explain his suggestion? Is there any other faster way to do this?

Comment: Please add a tag to your question for the specific database platform you are using.

Comment: Hi Sam, the interviewer didn't mention about the specific SQL database, I guess he means any SQL database such as MySQL or Azure SQL

Comment: If the question is agnostic to a specific database, I would recommend ditching the left outer join and use the NOT EXISTS clause instead. It is part of the SQL standard so most database platforms are going to implement it. In my experience, NOT EXISTS (and EXISTS) are orders of magnitude faster than outer joins.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work for an in-depth look at the EXISTS clause.

Comment: *The interviewer suggest a better way that I should sort the table_B first and then run the left join since it could reduce the iteration time to `n*log(k)` (not very sure If I got/understand his suggestion )* This is outright stupidity. (1) You must not sort but create suitable indices. (2) If the indices are absent the server will sort the rows before joining with high probability (the more the amount of rows the higher this probability).

Comment: ... (3) There is no construction in SQL which may tell "sort this table before joining". You may sort in subquery - but this sorting will be ignored in outer query. Moreover, if you'd apply sorting without limiting in the subquery then the server will cut off this sorting from SQL code during the execution plan building.

Comment: Hi Akina, thank you for your suggestions. Could you tell me a little bit more about how to create suitable indices? If the indices are missing, could you show me what is the proper answer to the interviewers' question

Comment: Especially I don't really understand the log function here. How can I teach the SQL not to run n*k iteration and show the solution?

Comment: In SQL you tell the DBMS what data to get. It's up to the DBMS how to get it. A perfect optimizer would come up with the same execution plan for your anti join, for a `NOT EXISTS` query and a `NOT IN` query. When a DBMS is very young it may tend to be faster on joins, because its programmers focused on this. In that case your anti join may be the fastest method. I would always go with `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, though, for readabilty. If the interviewer thinks, you can tell the DBMS how exactly to get the data, they are wrong or they have a particular DBMS with a proprietary solution in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is good, but...

> since it needs to go through n*k times iterations

That is false if you `table_B` has `INDEX(customer_id)`; then it becomes n*1

I would use a semi-join:

```
SELECT customer_id
    FROM table_A AS A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM table_B AS B
                WHERE B.customer_id = A.customer_id );
```

The two formulations are logically identical, but I don't know if the Optimizer is that smart.

In MySQL, the lookup in table_B would reach int a BTree, which is technically O(logN) for a point query.  That is, the index is already sorted, and your interviewer does not understand that indexing is the right way to approach the problem.

If some other engine uses a HASH index, the speed is roughly the same.

Sorting has been well researched (even 60 years ago); it is *provably* O(N*logN).  (This is based on the number of 2-way comparisons needed to sort an arbitrary list.  Sorting 1K rows can be done in about 1000*10 comparisons.)  That "big-O" notation is used for judging complexity as you scale a problem.  O(N) < O(N*logN) < O(N^2) < O(e**N)

Your k*n is like O(N^2) as *both* k and n grow.

Your interviewer failed to say what is to be done after table_B has been sorted.  Maybe he wanted you to sort both on customer_id, then walk through them in parallel.  That would be O(N*logN) + O(N*logN) + O(N), which simplifies to O(N*logN).

If you had challenged the interviewer on his "outright stupidity" (politely), he would either

- give you a thumbs down due to his embarrassment, or
- give you the job because you were smarter than he.

You are now smarter, so *that* question won't stump you again.

**The response to the interviewer**

(Ignore the comment about sorting, and say...)

> That query is efficient if `table_B` has an index index starting with `customer_id`.  Depending on the optimizer, `NOT EXISTS` might be even better.