# How does Exists exactly works when using it like a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel clumsy because I have been looking for information on how exists exactly works and I continue without undetsanding it.

Imagine I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM suppliers
 WHERE EXISTS (select *
                 from orders
                where suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id);
```

What I know from exists is that if its argument query is true, the outer query will be executed.
So imagine that the inner query is true, then the output would be all the table as the outer query is:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM suppliers
```

But actually it is not, I think I'm missing something when exists is used to make inner join like in this example but I don't understand...

I have taken this example of this post and I have read all the answers and I didn't understand it really well.. : [How do SQL EXISTS statements work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846882/how-do-sql-exists-statements-work)

I really appreciate all the possible help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you're missing is that the subquery is correlated to the main query using the condition `suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id`. So the `EXISTS()` condition is only true if matching rows are found, just like in a `JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar yes I know, but if at least one record meets the condition `suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id` then   `SELECT * FROM suppliers` , so why all the table of suppliers is not shown?

Comment: If every supplier has orders, it will return the entire suppliers table. But if there are some suppliers that have no orders, those suppliers won't be included in the result.

Comment: How is the inner query changing then? I mean if the suppliers that doesn't have orders are not shown is because the inner query (the argument of exists) is changing. I am not seeing how is it changing, isn't the inner query the same always?

Comment: Each time the inner query is executed, it's using the `suppliers.supplier_id` from the current row of the outer query. So `EXISTS()` only returns true if *that* supplier ID returns any results.

Comment: It is a correlated subquery, producing different results for different suppliers rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially implementing the following pseudo-code loop:

```
for row in suppliers
    current_supplier_id = row.supplier_id
    perform subquery: 
        SELECT * 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.supplier_id = current_supplier_id
    if the subquery returns any results, add row to the result set
```

Now you should be able to see how the inner query is changing each time. It's just looking for one particular `supplier_id`, not any of them.

Comment: well detailed answer, thanks